# WebClient ignores ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, webclient

I use a WebClient to get data from an external website from my MVC5 project:

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var result = client.DownloadString(url);

            return this.Content(result);
        }
```

However, the requested URL uses TLS, but we are in development phase, so they use their own certificate which is obviously not legit. Therefore, I receive this exception:

```
[IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.]
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +6587998
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +132
   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +59
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +247
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +137
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) +119
   System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state) +38
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) +166
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) +21
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) +64
   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result) +797
   System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +52
   System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +19
   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async) +142
```

I have read many other articles, so I add these code in my `Global.asax` `Application_Start` method:

```
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            (s, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
            {
                return true;
            };
```

However, the result stays the same. I even tried to put breakpoint at the Callback set line, and 1 at the `return true` line. At the start, the breakpoint is hit as intented. However, when the WebClient calls, the breakpoint at `return true` line is never hit.

Does `WebClient` uses another CallBack method? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you download that url using a web brower? If the external website use an untrusted certificate, you can tell your web-browser to trust that certificate. You can also tell `WebClient` to trust or ignore that certificate because WebClient is a just like a web-browser.

Comment: @damphat Yes. I pasted the URL to browser, and the browser warns me about the certification not getting signed. I could choose to ignore and proceed anyway. However, for WebClient, I couldn't do that (or, exactly don't know exactly how to do that successfully).

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you have to add something like this

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 
                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But it depends which protocols it supports. You can check it here
https://www.ssllabs.com

This results are for me from this website
Protocols

> TLS 1.2   Yes TLS 1.1 Yes  TLS 1.0    No  SSL 3   No  SSL 2   No